# How do I detemine the max path length allowed when creating a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, nio

How do I detemine the max path length allowed when creating a file in Java.
I'm using Java 7 so can make use of Java NIO2 if that helps but how can I detemine the max length allowed on the filesystem for a file and ensure I do not try and create a file that has such an invalid path.

I want to shorten the path (substring) before I try and create it not deal with a problem afterwards especially because the exception/error message could vary from fileystem to filesystem.

I don't want to hard code length per platform, that wouldnot work anyway as a Windows application could access an OSX filessystem ectera.

It only fails when an attempt is made to create file
i.e

```
 try
        {

            Path p = Paths.get("C:/User/Mesh/kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.txt");
            Files.createFile(p);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

gives

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\User\Mesh\kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.txt: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:229)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:586)
```

Compare to Java 6 method

```
try
        {
            //File file = new File("C:/User/Mesh/kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.txt");
            Path p = Paths.get("C:/User/Mesh/kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.txt");
            p.toFile().createNewFile();
            //boolean result=file.isFile();
            //System.out.println("Result is:"+result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

gives totally different error

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
```

but irrelvant really because I want to do something before file is created

EDIT:
Looks like 255 characters is a good default http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename anyway

Comment: how would that help it needs to work on any system not just my own

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Eclipse, if you're using that, has it's own (rather severe) path length limitations.

Comment: I can't offhand find a way to materialize this value.  Probably best to simply catch exceptions when trying to open a file and deal with it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `getPath` in `java.nio.file.FileSystem` that can be used to create a valid path name, or else it throws an InvalidPathException. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: Thanks that looks useful, but I think for now Im just going to harcoded to 255 chars

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
boolean success = true;
File testFile = new File("/a/really/long/name");
try {
    success = testFile.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // anyway check the exception, the problem could have been other
    // for example: duplicate name, lack of permissions, etc.
    success = false;
}

if (!success) {
    // error creating file
}
```

Comment: What i wanting was a way to check the filename is valid before I create it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I don't think that can be done. The simplest way would be trying to create it and in case of error handle it, as shown above